# How to initialise an instance other than the current class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, oop, class, proxy, instance

I want to initialize instances of different class based on the initial params. For example, I want to have different behavior for `Hello.new(true)` and `Hello.new(false)`. Be precise, I want them to create **instance of different classes**.

How could I achieve that in Ruby?

```
class Name1
end

class Name2
end

class Hello
  def initialize(opts)
    if opts
      Name1.new
    else
      Name2.new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: is the answer given by Simone,is the one you are looking for? If so then accept it or give us more specific information about your need. As your requirement is not clear.

Comment: The *implied* requirement is that `Hello.new( nil )` returns an object of class `Name2` and that `Hello.new( some_non_nil_options )` returns an object of class `Name1`. Simone's answer is effectively advice to *not* try to over-ride `new` in this way, but to use a different method name where it is easier and more standard to return  an object that might in one of some possible classes. It's a good answer IMO, but would not meet requirements if the method used absolutely has to be `Hello.new` for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called `Factory` pattern (at least, a simple version). It's possible to split the `new` process invoking `allocate` and `initialize` manually, but I don't recommend it.

The main reason is because it totally counter-intuitive. You'll (almost) never find a Ruby library behaving like this.

Instead, I suggest you to use a different method. For example, `#factory`.

```
class Name1
end

class Name2
end

class Hello
  def self.factory(opts)
    klass = if opts
      Name1
    else
      Name2
    end
    klass.new
  end
end

Hello.factory(...)
```

Comment: I didn't get the difference between `if-else` block of OP and you. Can you help me here?

Comment: It's the same. I return the class name as variable and then invoke .new on it. The main difference, which is the key of the answer, is that I use a `.factory` method instead of changing `.new`

Comment: ok got you. How your one is more beneficial than OP. Just to learn the concept I asked. As both code producing two objects.OP's one is producing the `Name` object at the time of object of `Hello` creation. And your code doing that via method,later of the object creation of `Hello`. So logically what's the difference between two codes of you and OP?

Comment: @RubyLovely: The OP's code doesn't return the objects from `new`. Instead the OP gets an empty object of class `Hello`. That's just due to how `initialize` works. Simone's answer is about how to place pretty much the same code into a slightly different part of Ruby's class and object model, so that it works as intended, and according to a well-known pattern that a lot of OO coders will recognise from Ruby and many other languages.